# Ionic - Convert Image to grayscale

Tags: image, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my app the user takes a picture through the OS camera app, with it's path passed back to my app.

I want to convert that image to grayscale.
I am not sure of how to do this.

I've seen plenty tutorials on how to convert the image to grayscale using `<canvas>` (e.g. http://www.vapidspace.com/coding/2012/02/26/converting-images-to-grayscale-using-the-canvas/ or many others).

The thing is that i don't want the user to see the canvas at all (no flickering, too while showing and hiding it instantly) while i convert the image to grayscale.

**My Question**
After loading the image file content. How do i convert it to grayscale?

Comment: If you set the `canvas` display to `none` you won't see any flickering.

Comment: Recent browsers also support a [CSS grayscale filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/grayscale). Check the supported browsers on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)

Comment: @Phonolog How would that apply to my question?... I want to modify the image, not it's representation on a page.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, maybe you can edit your question with what exactly you want to do with the picture after you convert it to grayscale...